# difference in standard deviation calculated on different SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, standard-deviation

I am running two queries on two different `SQL Server instances`, one is a `"13.0.4474.0"`, the other is a `"13.0.4411.0"`.

They calculate the `STDEV` of the same set of approximately `8K bigint numbers`.
The `STDEV` comes out different!

I am sure the numbers are the same because before applying the `STDEV` I select all the numbers and I compare them. They. Are. The. Same. (I put the two sets in Excel , order them and take the differences on the various rows. It always comes out 0, so they are the same)

- Their `Sum` is the same.
- Their `Count` is the same.

The `STDEV` is slightly different:

```
2880.01921436887 and 2880,01956854958
```

If I calculate the `STDEV` of the same numbers in `Excel` I get a third number but in this case, who cares, it must be due to something in the implementation in the two programs.

But why in the same SQL Server?

The query I am using has no `OVER nor ORDER BY` (that makes the function not deterministic)

Here's the code on the first machine:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

SELECT 
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS C, 
    SUM(CAST(MyBigintField AS BIGINT)) AS S, 
    STDEV(MyBigintField) AS D 
FROM 
    dbo.myTable 
WHERE 
    MyBigintField >= 108000000 
    AND MyBigintField < 108010000
```

These numbers are NOT changed by any process. The select keeps spitting out the same two different numbers.

On the second machine the query is exactly the same, except for the name of the field and the table because I am on another machine. Once again, if I just collect the numbers with this same query (just using a * instead of COUNT,SUM,STDEV) I get the same numbers.

I am doing a lot of tries and I see that if I add exactly 1 to the biggest of the bigint numbers in one machine, then I get the same STDEV I have on the second one. If I add just 1 to any other number, the ST.DEV does not change, and this is something that is more natural because these numbers are of the order of 100 million and they are 8 thousands, so adding just 1 to one of them shouldn't change the st.dev in the first 11 decimal places.

I guess it is something due to rounding but I can't understand exactly.

---

[EDIT]

After a while I arrived at this VERY strange thing:

```
DECLARE @min as BIGINT
DECLARE @max as BIGINT
DECLARE @step as BIGINT
SET @min = 1900000001
SET @max = 1900000050
SET @step = 1
;WITH mycte AS (
    SELECT @min AS i
        UNION ALL
    SELECT i + @step
    FROM mycte
    WHERE i <= @max - @step
)
SELECT COUNT(*) myCount, stdev(i) myStDev
FROM mycte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This gives me myCount = 50 (correct) and myStDev = 0 (on both machines)
I checked and the CTE correctly gives me the 50 numbers from 1900000001 and 1900000050 (both inclusive).

How is that possible?

If I try again but the range goes up to 1900000150 then the STDev is different from 0 but it seems different from the one calculated with Excel (I tried both ST.DEV.P and ST.DEV.S)

Maybe it has to do with the fact that I am working with bigint numbers whose value is quite near maxint?

Comment: dfdundako: why "no research"? I have spent the last hour trying to understand this think. ow do you think I found out about the non-deterministic aspect of the function in case of the use of OVER? I read the documentation. THIS IS RESEARCH! Why would this question be NOT useful, in case there really is a reason for this difference? I do not agree with your edit

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @JohannesWentu Did I say something? I edited out a few things and made spelling changes.

Comment: There is a -1 on the question that means: "this question doesn't show any effort bla bla bla...". Since you were the only one working on it I assume it was you. If I am wrong, I am sorry to have addressed you. It's quite frustrating to ask for help and being downvoted after 2 minutes. If I have a way to redirect my criticism to the correct person, please let me know and accept my excuses

Comment: I've done my own calculations to confirm an SD calc, and it didn't get their values - are you familar with how to calculate SD via summations etc?  I'll send you my test code

Comment: Unfortunately "deterministic" doesn't mean "guaranteed the same across servers", just "the result will not change on this server if the database doesn't". The optimizer tends to love performance a lot more than it likes giving stable floating-point results. For starters, try adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` on both servers to see if the result changes yet again when you eliminate parallelism.

Comment: @Jeroen - S.D should surely always be the same for the same values

Comment: I don't get the same answer as MS - investigating  SELECT dq.theirSD, 
   dq.EsigmaX2  - mu * mu MyVariance, 
   SQRT(dq.EsigmaX2  - mu * mu) MyCalc  from  
(select  stdev(PagedSystemMemorySize) theirSD, 
  sum(cast(PagedSystemMemorySize as float) * PagedSystemMemorySize) / count(0) as EsigmaX2, 
  sum(cast(PagedSystemMemorySize as float)) /count(0) mu from isproclog) DQ

Comment: Thank you Cato. I am not implementing ST.DEV on my own, I am using the builtin function so I was expecting the same result.

Thank you @Jeroen Mostert: I will try to add the maxdop. I know the two server have a different maxdop default (one is 2, the other is 1)

Comment: Even afer adding OPTION (MAXDOP 1), the results do not change from before.
I also noticed something peculiar: the result is given with a different decimal separator on the two servers, one with a comma, the other with a dot. I don't know if this could mean something.

Comment: @Cato: the outcome of aggregate floating-point operations is critically dependent on the order of the same. I really wouldn't put it past the SQL Server implementation to not care very much about getting "the same result for the same values", let alone optimizing for numerical stability. I can't even think of a way to force the optimizer to process rows in an order for aggregates, except through trickery.

Comment: Another thing to check (probably not relevant, but hey) is that the compatibility level of the databases is the same on both servers. There were [some changes](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261/) going to 130 from earlier versions (although this should not affect standard aggregates). Ditto for some more advanced optimizer flags (check trace flags and database options).

Comment: As far as I can see, the versions are very very similar (I posted them at the beginning of my post) so it would be a struck of misfortune to have a change in DEVST logic exactly between those two versions

Comment: The logic is almost certainly the same (unless they slipped in some changes without revealing it in the CU release notes), but this still does not guarantee identical results, as that would also require processing the rows in the same order (and possibly, if you're unlucky, the same hardware, if the optimizer uses different instruction sets on different processors). If you haven't already done so, consider restoring a backup of the database from one server on the other server to at least guarantee that the data is physically (on-disk) identical, as are the database settings.

Comment: sorry I'm using the wrong sd formula, they are using the sample sd formula where you divide by n-1

Comment: row order shouldn't matter on stdev or AVG though, just like it shouldn't change COUNT - or am I missing something?  If you did something like top 1000, and there were ties, you might get different rows though, but surely this SQL is deterministic in values returned (even if not in order, which doesn't change the values in this case)

Comment: @ Jeroen Mostert  - I'd only expect numeric round off at a very high end of precision, not the difference the questioner is seeing, sorry I didn't see your explanation earlier - yes it could explain it, but I'd check the sum(x squared) value, because he could have cancelling differences in his data.

Comment: If you can have NULL values, compare the ANSI NULL settings if the servers

Comment: Is there any chance you can post the actual values or—preferably, since you said there are thousands of them—some subset of the actual values that causes a similar discrepancy to appear? I'd like to see if I can reproduce the result.

Answer (score 0):

here's a CTE to check any set of values - if you change the SQL in 'd' to return any list of numbers aliased as y, then you should get 'theirSD' is equal to 'mySD' - if two different servers give different values, then I'd expect sigma, sigma2, or n to differ between them

I made my own calculations based on the definition of s.d, which is the sum of (x - mu) squared, then divided by n-1 (in this case)

```
with d as (select  cast(x as float) y from tempt)
    ,calcs as (select  stdev(y) theirSD, 
                        avg(y) theirAV,
                        sum(y) Sigma,
                        sum(y *y) sigma2,
                        sum(y) / count(0) myAV,
                        count(0) n
                        from d) 
    select *, sqrt((sigma2 - sigma/n * sigma ) / (n-1)) mysd     from calcs
```

my formula requires casting as float - if left at bigint, it doesn't quite wrok due to rounding, but their figure still looks right with bigint

I think you need to check the sum(x * x) factor in your data, then if COUNT and SUM(x) seem identical, it's probably the numeric round off effect postulated by Jeroem